# referenced relationships sql server analysis Services, How can i create it

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, olap-cube

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpniD.png)I'm beginner in **SSAS**, actually I work on **SSAS** Olap cube I have an issue which is I can not add customer fields to charge dimension or to charge fact (to be displayed on power bi )

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is:

1. Add dimension to the cube
2. Open "Dimension Usage" tab
3. Click on a cell crossing Measure Group vs Dimension
4. Use "Referenced" type and select another dimension as a Reference

But please provide more details:
What have you tried before asking a question here?
Why it didn't help?
What are you trying to achieve (with simple example in Excel, plain text etc.)? Like Customer: A,B,C, Charge: X,Y,Z. Their relations. What is your expectation.